# How could I get BundleContext in Spring DM?

Tags: spring, osgi, spring-dm

I am newly on Spring DM and I would like to access Bundlecontext. My problem is that I have a bundle with Activator, but it does not have xml config file. I cannot touch this bundle, then I need to access to BundleContext and serviceReference to obtain the service in my bundle. I am using Spring DM in my bundle. So, how could I get BundleContext?

Thanks!

Regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to implement `BundleContextAware` and the other one, if you don't want to rely on DM and its mechanisms:

```
BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring DM documentation](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.1.0/reference/html/bnd-app-ctx.html#bnd-app-ctx%3aaccess-bnd-ctx) says you should implement the `BundleContextAware` interface to get your bundle context. However, it also rightly explains you should hardly ever use it, and are perhaps better off using Spring DMs injection mechanisms if you need access to some service.